# aws api gateway client-side ssl certificate verification with nginx

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, nginx, aws-api-gateway

Similar to this other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33081349/aws-api-gateway-client-authentication-and-nginx) I'm attempting to verify SSL Client Certificates with nginx that have been sent via AWS API Gateway.

I noticed that in the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-client-side-ssl-authentication.html), AWS API Gateway only sends the client certificate along with HTTP requests. Does this mean that HTTPS should not be configured?

Contrary to the link to the question I posted above, the domain that nginx is hosted on does not have https certificates setup.

Any help, or a link to a working configuration using ssl_verify_client without ssl configured for the domain would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the nginx configuration I'm working with currently:

```
daemon off;

events {
  worker_connections  4096;
}

http {
  server {
    listen 2345 default_server;

    ssl_trusted_certificate /certs/api-gateway.crt;
    ssl_client_certificate /certs/api-gateway.crt;
    ssl_verify_client on;

    ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers "HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5 or HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!3DES";
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    location /ping {
      proxy_pass http://my.http.public.endpoint.com;
    }

    location / {
      if ($ssl_client_verify != SUCCESS) { return 403; }
      proxy_pass http://my.http.public.endpoint.com;
      proxy_set_header X-Client-Verify $ssl_client_verify;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're misinterpreting the docs, though the reason is easily understandable.

> API Gateway will use the certificate for all calls to HTTP integrations in your API.

The phrase to parse is "HTTP integrations" -- as opposed to Lambda or AWS Service proxy -- not "HTTP" as in "HTTP without SSL".  They're using "HTTP" in a generic sense to describe a type, not the specific details of the transport.

SSL client certificates do not work without HTTPS, and won't work without an SSL certificate configured on the server.

Comment: Of course, thanks for pointing this out. I've managed to get this working now.

Comment: I have a similar setup but we are using cloudflare Universal SSL without any certificates. Would it work in this scenario?

Comment: If you don't have a certificate, then you don't have SSL @rtexal so it isn't clear what you're asking.

Comment: cloudflare does use ECDSA certificates but they are on the CDN. communication between cloudflare and our server is not encrypted. this somewhat mimicks using https without needing to host our own certificates on the server itself

Comment: Ah, so, you have SSL on the front-end, but not on the back-end.  Your site has a cert, but your app server itself doesn't.  It seems unlikely that Cloudflare will actually solicit a client certificate, or provide a mechanism for you to authenticate it, or pass information about that cert to you (it would have to be injected into the request headers by them, for you to make any use of it).  This question is about authenticating pass-through requests from API Gateway using a client cert, and it doesn't seem like something you could do in your setup.

Comment: I copy the client SSL cert provided by AWS into a file and point it to ssl_client_certificate but it returns me "400 No required SSL certificate was sent". Using letsencrypt for the server-side SSL (if it matters). Does nginx support self-signed client certs and if not, how do I use this AWS client cert.

Comment: @creavery I'd be happy to help with this if possible, but I would respectfully suggest that you post this as a new question, referencing this one if appropriate, after verifying that it has not already been answered, here.  Yes, this should work with nginx; Lets Encrypt should not be relevant; at first glance, it sounds as if you did not configure API Gateway to actually *send* the client certificate with each request.  You might also check http://serverfault.com since this seems to be a bit on the edge between programming and system administration.

Comment: @michael-sqlbot http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34175361/client-side-ssl-not-working-with-aws-api-gateway (thanks - looking fwd to resolving this). I am using the Test button for the resource where I can specify the client certificate when issuing a request. So I believe the client cert is being sent with the request, just that my server side is not configured properly.

Comment: @DavidKelley I'm trying to get the same working with no luck. From the comments it looks like you got this working. would you mind sharing what you had to do? I get the cloudfront error without client certificate or 400 Bad request error. Appreciate any help.

Comment: @Sanjeev we had to use our domain certificates inside nginx with the client certificate provided by API Gateway. You can't achieve this without using SSL with nginx, subsequently meaning you can't use any service (AWS Certificate Manager for example) that manages SSL for you

Comment: @DavidKelley thanks. I have a domain certificate issued by CA and added to nginx - works as expected. As soon as I add the client certificate from API gateway the whole thing blows up. Here is my nginx.conf.https://gist.github.com/snandam/ce28382923519766e22987d1e4923d9c

Comment: I would prefer doing it from the Certificate Manager instead, rather then pushing the certs in .ebextensions and pointing to them through the nginx/puma conf files.